# How to remove dynamically added append element after submit and validate them?

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, datatables

With jQuery, I have a button that adds an input field element on click. How do I remove the added elements after successful submit to the database? And how should I validate the dynamically added fields as they have dynamic names?

This is the snippet of the form:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap");
        var count = 0;

        $('p#add_field').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            count += 1;
            $('#container').append(
                '<div>\n\
                   <label>Weight</label><input type="text" id="weight_' + count + '" name="weight[]' + '"/>\n\
                <a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a><br>'
            );
        });

        $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { 
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent('div').remove();
            x--;
        })
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="POST" id="productForm">
<div class="messages"></div>
   <label>Product</label><input type="text" id="product" name="product"><br>
   <div id="container" class="input_fields_wrap">
      <label>Available options:</label>
      <div>
         <p id="add_field"><button type="button" href="#"><span>Add new</span></button></p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <button type="submit" name="btnSubmit">Save to database</button>
</form>
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ashonko/6p2kvbxL/2/) of the working form.

I have been trying to use the [datatables](https://datatables.net/) plugin to display the data of the database. And so far, I have came with this to validate the `Product` field. But have no idea how to validate the dynamic `Weight1 fields and remove the fields after submit to database.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var name = $("#product").val();

    if (product == "") {
        $("#product").closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
        $("#product").after('<p class="text-danger">The product field is required</p>');
    } else {
        $("#product").closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
        $("#product").closest('.form-group').addClass('has-success');
    }

    if (product) {
        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr('action'),
            type: form.attr('method'),
            data: form.serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {

                // remove the error 
                $(".form-group").removeClass('has-error').removeClass('has-success');

                if (response.success == true) {
                    $(".messages").html('Success');

                    // reset the form
                    $("#productForm")[0].reset();

                } else {
                    $(".messages").html('Failed.');
                }
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get handle to input field created dynamically using `$("[id*='weight']")`.

The below sample removes all dynamic input fields.

```
$("[id*='weight']").each(function(){
    $(this).parent("div").remove();
})
```

The below is the sample which I have written when clicked upon `Validate` button. The example below is just to give an idea. You can modify it as you want.

```
$("#btnValidate").on("click", function(){
    var error = false;
    $("[id*='weight']").each(function(){
        if ($(this).val().trim() === "") error = true;
    });

    if (error)
    {
        alert("Please udpate weight for all rows");
        return false;
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for effort. :)

Comment: Hi, can you help me here how may I reset the `var count` back to `0` after the submit?

Comment: Instead of `var count = 0;` use `var count = $("[id*='weight']").length;`. With this change you no need to bother about resetting count variable.